# tracking sheet creation for SharePoint

Tags: issue-tracking

Can someone guide me on how to create or how to put together tracking sheet of different team so each team can access each other data? I am very new in share-pointtra.

Comment: Could you give more information about what SharePoint (2010, 2013, 2016, Online) you are using and what you want to get. Please give some more sentences that describe your goal and how you tried to attempt.

Comment: Different team of hiring department HR. SP 2013 to 16 guidance. got an excel file that is messy, named Vacancy Report Tracking Spreadsheet with about 10 colums and about 500 rows... Learning on how to organize such kind of file for a beter browsing of HR boss...